# WORD dynamic referencing from source list

Tags: microsoft-word

For WORD, I want to be to insert a citation from a list of references, and add/remove to/from the reference list if the citation exists or not.

```
i.e.
This guy said this^1
This guy said that^2
```

If I were to remove

```
This guy said this^1
```

then I want the reference (1) at the end of my document to also be removed, and for the other references to update by number.

```
1 Jon, Smith., (2010) SOME TITLE
2 HARRY, Mill., (2014) SOME TITLE       # become (1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you described is the standard behaviour of endnotes in Word.

You can insert them at references tab - insert endnote.

Delete them by simply deleting the number, it'll automatically delete reference at the end of your document and also renumber remaining endnotes.

[image]

Comment: Right, but If i remove the reference then I have to fully write it back in again.

 if I want to add it back later. Is there a way to store references? So i can just pull it in again?

Comment: No, there is no way that in Word. And I don't think any other word processor would have such functionality.